# EXC_BAD_ACCESS drawing graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm drawing graph and for that I use `SHLineGraphView` now after drawing one graph I need to remove that and dray again.  in line

```
 CGPathMoveToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, plot.xPoints[0].y);
```

I am getting  get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Message.
this is my function. I add NSZombieEnabled YES in my scheme

```
- (void)drawPlot:(SHPlot *)plot {

NSDictionary *theme = plot.plotThemeAttributes;

CAShapeLayer *backgroundLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
backgroundLayer.frame = self.bounds;
backgroundLayer.fillColor = ((UIColor *)theme[kPlotFillColorKey]).CGColor;
backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[backgroundLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[backgroundLayer setLineWidth:((NSNumber *)theme[kPlotStrokeWidthKey]).intValue];

CGMutablePathRef backgroundPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];


UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
circleLayer.path = circle.CGPath;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.shadowColor =[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;

[self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

CGMutablePathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAShapeLayer *graphLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
graphLayer.frame = self.bounds;
graphLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
graphLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[graphLayer setStrokeColor:((UIColor *)theme[kPlotStrokeColorKey]).CGColor];
[graphLayer setLineWidth:((NSNumber *)theme[kPlotStrokeWidthKey]).intValue];

CGMutablePathRef graphPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

double yRange = [_yAxisRange doubleValue];
double yIntervalValue = yRange / INTERVAL_COUNT;

[plot.plottingValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)obj;

    __block NSNumber *_key = nil;
    __block NSNumber *_value = nil;

    [dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        _key = (NSNumber *)key;
        _value = (NSNumber *)obj;
    }];

    int xIndex = [self getIndexForValue:_key forPlot:plot];

    double height = self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE;
    double y = height - ((height / ([_yAxisRange doubleValue] + yIntervalValue)) * [_value doubleValue]);
    (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x = ceil((plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x);
    (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).y = ceil(y);
}];


CGPathMoveToPoint(graphPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, plot.xPoints[0].y);
CGPathMoveToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, plot.xPoints[0].y);

int count = _xAxisValues.count;
for(int i=0; i< count; i++){
    CGPoint point = plot.xPoints[i];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(graphPath, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(circlePath, NULL, CGRectMake(point.x - 5, point.y - 5, 10, 10));
}
CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave + PLOT_WIDTH, self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE);
CGPathCloseSubpath(backgroundPath);
backgroundLayer.path = backgroundPath;
graphLayer.path = graphPath;
circleLayer.path = circlePath;
CGPathRelease(backgroundPath);
CGPathRelease(circlePath);
CGPathRelease(graphPath);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.fromValue = @(0.0);
animation.toValue = @(1.0);
[graphLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

backgroundLayer.zPosition = 0;
graphLayer.zPosition = 1;
circleLayer.zPosition = 2;

[self.layer addSublayer:graphLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];

NSUInteger count2 = _xAxisValues.count;
for(int i=0; i< count2; i++){
    CGPoint point = plot.xPoints[i];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btn.tag = i;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, 40, 40);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, kAssociatedPlotObject, plot, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    [self addSubview:btn];
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: use NSZombie to find out error.

Comment: Check that all the values arent' nil.

Comment: Check if plot.xPoints[] contains anything.

Comment: Yes plot.xPoints[]  contained data

Comment: Share the crash logs here, as @Rushabh said - enable NSZombie to find the error/exception/logs.

Comment: I haven't crash log.But I add NSZombieEnabled.